# Is it possible to change a web site inside a Xamarin web view?

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

We want to open a web site inside a Xamarin web view but we want to hide some parts of it.

Is it possible to manipulate the web site's DOM to for example, hide a banner, or a button?

Also, we want to hide those things before they even appear so the user don't see them disappearing.

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is yes.... BUT if you do not own that site, then that is a huge copyright/trademark/TOS/ethical/legal/... issue, if you do own that site, produce a a different version of it for your mobile needs.

Comment: No problem the site owner is a client for whom we are developing the app and some parts of it will just reuse the existing mobile web site. That is all agreed.

Comment: Then can you just detect mobile devices and serve a mobile web view